# Watch variable error in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, swift, debugging, lldb, watch

I'm trying to watch a variable by pausing on a breakpoint, right clicking on the variable I want to watch and selecting Watch "someVariable", but I get the following error:

> error: no variable named ‘someVariable’ found in this frame.

This seems to happen with any variable I try. How can I properly watch a variable for changes?

Comment: Can you print those variables, i.e. does: "expr someVariable" work?  If not, then it sounds like you didn't build with debug information or something.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to get watchpoints to work at all with Xcode and Swift. I suspect it's broken for Swift, and hope they get it working in the future.

Comment: Watchpoints work in swift for some very simple object like Int's.  But many swift objects under the covers are more complex than they seem, and what exactly to watch is not clear...